# How to use GROUP BY and JOIN in a SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

I have two tables called "Player" and "Country":

Player

```
Person    Goals    Country
-------   -----    -------
Pogba       1      France
Pavard      1      France
Griezmann   2      France
Neymar      3      Brazil
Silva       2      Brazil
```

Country

```
Name      Continent
-------   --------------
France    Europe
Brazil    South America
```

I want to show the sum of goals for each country and display the country name, continent, and total goals
So, I would like my output to look like this:

```
Country  Continent       Goals
-------  -------------   ------
France   Europe          4
Brazil   South America   5
```

I can display Country & Continent together and Country & Goals together but I can't do all three.
Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT Country.Name, Country.Continent, SUM(Player.Goals)
FROM Player
INNER JOIN Country ON Player.Country = Country.Name
GROUP BY Player.Country;
```

Maybe I'm over simplifying it? I just don't know how I can get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below - add `Country.Continent` to `group by` too

```
SELECT Country.Name, Country.Continent, SUM(Player.Goals)
FROM Player
INNER JOIN Country ON Player.Country = Country.Name
GROUP BY Country.Name, Country.Continent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Country.Continent, Player.Country, SUM(Player.Goals)
FROM Player
INNER JOIN Country ON Player.Country = Country.Name
GROUP BY Country.Continent, Player.Country
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
SELECT Country.Name, Country.Continent, SUM(Player.Goals) as Goals
FROM Player
INNER JOIN Country ON Player.Country = Country.Name
GROUP BY Country.Name, Country.Continent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although adding `continent` to the `GROUP BY` is definitely one solution, there are others.

First, you can use an aggregation function on `continent`:

```
SELECT c.Name, MAX(c.Continent) as Continent, SUM(p.Goals)
FROM Player p JOIN
     Country c
     ON p.Country = c.Name
GROUP BY c.Name;
```

Or, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c.*,
       (SELECT SUM(p.Goals)
        FROM Player p
        WHERE p.Country = c.Name
       ) as goals
FROM Country c;
```

Note that both of these include table aliases, which make the query easier to write and read.

The advantage of the last version is that it avoids an aggregation in the outer query and also it allows you to easily choose as many columns from `Country` as you like.  It can also take advantage of an index on `Player(Country)`, if available -- although that is irrelevant on smaller amounts of data.